# what is a reasonable reputation count

Tags: discussion, reputation

We have all heard of our reputation count, and how it's constantly changing. I've been on StackExchange for only two days, and I currently have 23 reputation.

> all I'm asking for in this post is ***about how much reputation would make sense for a new user like me to have at the two or three day mark?***

And if I'm lower than average, ***what can I do to improve?***

I'm just curious.

Comment: How about changing StockExchange for Stackexchange ? We are not into exchanging stocks and bonds here

Comment: oops, my bad...

Comment: Hi @Imtherealsanic. Don't worry too much about reputation. Users have found that some of your answers did not meet the high quality standards for this site. Similarly, asking good questions is a trained skill. The system has rate-limited you.  You should be able to ask questions again later today, but please make sure you head the good advice given. I promise that good questions will be rewarded with upvotes and a higher reputation!

Comment: My other piece of advise: Earth Science Stack Exchange is a serious science site, used by scientists. We are thrilled if younger members want to actively contribute, but please don't feel bad if you find it difficult to provide questions and answers that the community finds valuable. Don't take it personally, and we hope you want to hang around and learn :)

Comment: oh okay. I guess I can understand why stackexchange is taken seriously, because I was wondering earlier why my questions and posts are disliked. But now that I know the site is a community of _real scientists,_ I understand why dislikes are placed. Thanks for the advice! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of this site, and other Stack Exchange sites, is to gain knowledge or share knowledge, by asking or answering questions - not to acquire reputation points. This isn't a game like Candy Crush, where the aim is to accumulate points.

There is no specific pattern or average trend for acquiring reputation. It depends on how many questions have been asked during a specific period of time and how many questions anyone can answer. Not everyone has the knowledge to answer all the questions asked, or the time.

Some of our members may only be competent to answer questions about weather and climate, others only about geology, some about geology and weather and climate.

The other things that are important are, are the questions valid for the site and worthy of its members to answer. Likewise, the quality of answers is one factor that determines the number of up votes an answer receives, in addition to the number of members qualified to review and vote on the answer.

Comment: oh, okay. I thought It was to build reputation and trust in others.

Comment: I use scratch.mit.edu, and the object of it is more about making projects and building a good **reputation**.